# Jenkins Groovy to parse console output and mark build failure

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, salt, groovy

What would be a Groovy or pipeline step to parse Jenkins console output, identify a string and mark the build as failure if the string is matched?

Comment: When you say "pipeline" - do you mean "declarative pipeline"?

Answer (score 5):

This question seems similar to [another on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188512/search-through-console-output-of-a-jenkins-job#36190644), but seems to be a close, but not exact duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018509/jenkinsfile-build-log

To quote those :

> if you just want to check, that your log contains string myTestString you can just call manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*')
>
> If you want to get some information from the first matching line you can use manager.getLogMatcher(regexp)

You could use the [Groovy flow control](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control) to break the build - you just need a step to execute the test:

Following the example on the link :

```
node {
    stage('CheckLog') {
      steps {
        if (manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*')) {
          error("Build failed because of this and that..")    
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: the other two questions which this is similar to don't actually ask how to fail the build based on the contents of the log, just how to get the contents of the log, so technically, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Agree with the not duplicate, and usually we do not close cross duplicates unless there's really no more in this site approach on the question than the other site. In brief good job bringing this together and adding the missing point

Comment: Bruce, what if I want to match multiple patterns like if (manager.logContains('.*myTestString.*') || ('.*myTestString2.*')) )? I tried multiple options but it don't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by following [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444093/3513260).

You can use `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10)` (the `10` specifies that you want the last 10 lines) to get the last few lines of the log stream.

According to [this documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html#getLog-int-), this method returns a List of Strings (`List<String>`) where each index contains a single line of the log stream.

You can either search line-by-line for what you want, or you can combine the entire List into a single String using the `.join()` method.

To search the actual String, you can use the `.contains()` method or you can use a [RegExp](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/#_regular_expression_operators)